# How two flask app accessing same database

Tags: python, rest, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am going to build two flask REST API accessing same database.
Both 2 app have access to same table. For example I have Order table. Should i create OrderModel class on both of that 2 app or just one of them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating one project with three top level packages. Two of them are your flask applications, and one is a common package which houses modules which are shared between them.

```
your_project/
  app1/
    __init__.py
    app.py
  app2/
    __init__.py
    app.py
  commons/
    __init__.py
    models.py
```

In general, try to [avoid duplicating code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Also, this question might be better suited over at the [Software Engineering stack exchange site](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). It is a little too broad for SO.